# how to include custom seach elements in search form

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress post results section, I am looking for a way to add custom search parameters inside the wordpress search form as per the image attached,

[image]

Any solutions using hooks?

Thanks.

Comment: Check Default Class "WP_List_Table"

Comment: Will that handle search option?

Comment: Check this link http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/